# How to map guard-rspec to multiple different files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Say I have a `controller` in `app/controllers`

I have a series of `request` specs, one for each action in controller.  How do I tell [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) when watching a controller, to not only run `spec/controllers/controller_spec.rb` file but also run:

- `spec/requests/controller/index_spec`
- `spec/requests/controller/create_spec`
- `spec/requests/controller/update_spec`
- `spec/requests/controller/delete_spec`
- `spec/requests/controller/show_spec`

?

#### Update:

After @TheChamps help, I have this going.  Is this the correct approach for this use case?

```
  # Controller could be under api/v1 or root level.
  watch(%r{^app\/controllers(\/api\/v1\/)?(.+)_(controller)\.rb}) do |m|
    "spec/requests#{m[1]}#{m[2]}/"
  end
```

Comment: try adding `watch('app/controllers/(.*)_controller.rb') { |m| "spec/requests/#{m}" }`

Comment: any way to do that recursively? what if some controllers are nested under `api/v1/...` and some are not?

Comment: Did my suggestion work? And how do you differentiate the api controllers from the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `watch` command is pretty straight forward. Via [regex](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/regex.htm), you define where to watch and what to trigger.

### An example

Take this standard command from their docs:

```
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
```

**The first part**

```
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})
```

It looks for any files in the `app` directory which ends with `.rb` and takes the path as an argument - via `()`. If a matching file gets saved, for example `app/models/users.rb`, `model/users` gets passed on to:

**The block**

```
{ |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
```

By inserting the passed argument it looks for a specific file in the `spec` directory to trigger - `spec/models/user_spec.rb`.

### Your usecase

After saving your controller file, you want to trigger any files located under `/requests` and under a subfolder named *after* that controller. Now you should easily be able to understand this command, which achieves just that.

```
watch('app/controllers/(.*)_controller.rb') { |m| "spec/requests/#{m}" }
```

Comment: Hey @TheChamp, your answer definitely got me on the right track.  Not sure if it is too brittle though. Updated question. Is this in alignment with best practices?

Comment: if it's simply a case of in this directory or the other one, why not write two statements? I guess that's easier than writing complex regex

Comment: So add my suggestion and add your second usecase in a new statement

Comment: good point.  added and working.  marking as resolved.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

You can use `guard-rails` gem which generates by `$ guard init rails` a guard manifest file with default configuration for Rails.